# Critical dependencies - the request of a dependency is an expression Webpack

Tags: angularjs, express, webpack

I am using a service in my `angular` application to create `uibModal` as follows

```
function modal(modalConfig){
                  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: true,
                  template: require("../a/b/xyz.html"),
                  controller: modalConfig.controller,
                  size: modalConfig.size,
                  controllerAs: modalConfig.controllerAs,
                  bindToController : true,
                  resolve: modalConfig.resolveObj

                });
            }
```

Please note the line

```
 template: require("../a/b/xyz.html"),
```

I want to use a variable in its place like this

```
 template: require(modalConfig.templateUrl),
```

but when i use a variable in place of hard coded value `webpack` gives me

```
Critical dependencies:
83:22-54 the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I am not able to resolve this error. What can be the possible reason for it?

I have used `node-express` server for continuous `webpack` builds. I have looked at other answers too but they didn't solve my query.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After much hit and trial found the solution. What I did is this:

```
template: require("../../scripts" + modalConfig.templateUrl + ".html")
```

Assumptions

1. root folder under which all the file comes is `scripts`
2. and the relative path of this folder from the file in which the function is written is say `../../scripts`.
3. `../../scripts + modalConfig.templateUrl + ".html"` will form the correct path for the file to be used.

**Mandatory Note**

1. Always write some hardcoded path of root folder. Don't put it in variable. So this won't work:

```
var context = "../../scripts";
template: require(context + modalConfig.templateUrl + ".html")
```

The base path (as in a part of the actual path) has to be hardcoded for basic reference, as in it helps webpack to create a list of all the modules which might be needed for the dynamic requires.

Reason (from webpack [docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context#dynamic-require-rewriting)) , read [dynamic requires](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context#dynamic-require-rewriting).

Comment: Saved me a ton of time. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this issue in vuejs. Emphasis on this line: "Always write some hardcoded path of root folder. Don't put it in variable. so this won't work"

Comment: @hitautodestruct, Sorry but your comment is not clear to me. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi What I meant to say was that you helped me solve my issue with the line I quoted and it should be put in emphasis :-)

Comment: @jrh thanks for the updated links. Have updated them in answer.

Comment: A hug, you deserve a hug !