# Webpack code-splitting an app that uses relay

Tags: webpack, react-router, relay

[Sample github repo](https://github.com/rosskevin/my-relay-starter-kit/commit/da73f6ec79165ccc31f1ea84945c42358fd94d3f) (specific commit)

I'm diving into react/relay and want to make sure I'm setup for dev vs production to start.  We have a large application so code-splitting is a must.

I prefer JSX based `react-router` routes declarations, so I was happy to run into *[Implicit Code Splitting and Chunk Loading with React Router and Webpack](http://henleyedition.com/implicit-code-splitting-with-react-router-and-webpack/)* from [Evan Henley](https://github.com/echenley/react-router-huge-apps-refactor/tree/after).

With a few tweaks to the regex and for ES6, I was able to get his method working.  Clone [the repo](https://github.com/rosskevin/my-relay-starter-kit/commit/da73f6ec79165ccc31f1ea84945c42358fd94d3f), `npm install && npm start` and you will be able to navigate to different chunks (with the exception of todos).

^^^all of this works for the non-relay portions of the app - good stuff.

### Problem

Then...navigate to Todos (relay based).

```
Uncaught TypeError: _TodoListFooter2.default.getFragment is not a function
viewer 
Fragment 
(instrumented buildRQL.Fragment) 
buildContainerFragment
```

Our production app will wholly depend on relay.

Relay depends on a few static calls to classes such as `getFragment`.  In this case, webpack has pushed `TodoListFooter` into a *different* shared chunk so `TodoListFooter2` does not have `getFragment`.  By contrast, on the same line it breaks, `_AddTodoMutation2` is *in the same chunk* so a similar call `_AddTodoMutation2.default.getFragment('viewer')` works fine.

### Potential solutions

1. Use named chunks? [This commit](https://github.com/rosskevin/my-relay-starter-kit/commit/9d196695589f40645d85d91821cb50a73211f9ea) attempted to do so but it still pushed some code into a shared chunk (and failed with the same error)
2. Different code-splitting method that is relay compatible for static methods?
3. Something I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out that while Evan Henley's approach was nicer, I needed to alter it slightly in order to get it to be Relay compatible (with ES6+ `import`).

This required explicit `bundle?lazy` in the ES6 import to be compatible with relay.  [This commit](https://github.com/rosskevin/my-relay-starter-kit/commit/1901cc250c3160be4bf579174f6dc788422b1749) shows the primary differences I found to make it relay compatible.

Primarily, in Henley's code it required config of a webpack loader and an import such as:

```
import Landing from './components/Landing'
```

In contrast, my approach requires no extra webpack loader config with explicit bundle-loader lazy loading in the `import`:

```
import Landing from 'bundle?lazy!./components/Landing'
```

Henley's method makes cleaner route file import.  My approach makes it work with Relay and is a more explicit code-split via `import`, without having any additional `webpack.config.js` loader configurations via regex.

Each is fine, though my method is the only way I found to make it relay compatible.

Implementation:

```
type GetComponent = (location?: string, cb: GetComponentCB) => void

/**
 * Purpose: abbreviated expression so that we can read routes
 *
 * Background:
 *  - (failed) luqin/react-router-loader is awesome, but it is a Proxy and doesn't work with relay components.
 *    @see https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay/issues/161
 *
 *  - (failed) webpack dynamic requires need a hard path root (the rest can be an expression)
 *    at compile time and a regex is created
 *    @see https://webpack.github.io/docs/html#dynamic-requires
 *    @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37228426/2363935
 *
 *  - (succeeded ultimately) huge-app-splitting-refactor
 *    - uses bundle-loader, works with imports! and no path hardcoding!
 *    - approach doesn't work with Relay (quite as-is)
 *    - fixed approach with explicit bundle lazy imports!
 *    @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37575707/2363935
 *    @see http://henleyedition.com/implicit-code-splitting-with-react-router-and-webpack/
 *    @see https://github.com/echenley/react-router-huge-apps-refactor
 *
 * @param component
 * @returns {function()}
 */
export function lazy (lazyModule: Function): GetComponent {
  if (!lazyModule) {
    throw new Error('lazy() did not find the given module.  Check to be sure your import path is correct, and make sure you are pointing at a file with a ****default export****.')
  }
  return (location, cb) => {
    lazyModule((module) => {
      cb(null, module.default)
    })
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation */
import OrganizationQueries from '../../queries/OrganizationQueries'
import React from 'react'
import {Route} from 'react-router'
import {lazy} from '../../config/routes'
import Organization from 'bundle-loader?lazy!./Organization'

// protected by parent route
export default (
  <Route>
    <Route path='/organization' getComponent={lazy(Organization)} queries={OrganizationQueries} />
  </Route>
)
```

Comment: does you approach work with stuff like `Component.getFragment('viewer')`?

Comment: It does, the sample repo works and has the todos relay example (unstyled)