# Patternfly-ng Not working with Angular 5 : throws warning and if imported any module the app does not work

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I was trying to implement Patternfly-ng 0.13.6 with angular 5.0.0 and angular-cli 1.5.0 versions, but I am getting the below warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/patternfly-ng/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5675:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at ImportLazyContextDependency.getWarnings (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
    at Compilation.finish (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
    at F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (F:\SematreeProjects\Ng2\st-resource-allocation-ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
 @ ./node_modules/patternfly-ng/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./node_modules/patternfly-ng/src/app/wizard/wizard-substep.component.js
 @ ./node_modules/patternfly-ng/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NotificationModule } from 'patternfly-ng';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ......
  ],
  imports: [
    .......
    NotificationModule
  ],
  providers: [....],
  bootstrap: [....]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please help me out fixing this issue.

Comment: I just went through the walkthrough as well and am getting the same issue

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey please let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: Have you followed the steps in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000273/critical-dependencies-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression-webpack