# Vue nuxt require each url in object

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I would like to require by webpack each image path in my slider. At the moment i've got object that look like this:

```
 data() {
         return {
            slides: [
                {
                    title: 'The Ultimate Shopping Experinece',
                    description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, tempore.',
                    image:  require('~/assets/img/slides/slide1.png'),
                    button: 'Purchase Now'
                },
                {
                    title: 'The Ultimate ',
                    description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet',
                    image: require('~/assets/img/slides/slide2.png'),
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

that object i loop in vue template by v-for. My question is how to map this object without require inside each slides image? I would like to have clear object, something like this:

```
 data() {
     return {
        slides: [
            {
                title: 'The Ultimate Shopping Experinece',
                description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, tempore.',
                image:  '~/assets/img/slides/slide1.png',
                button: 'Purchase Now'
            },
            {
                title: 'The Ultimate ',
                description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet',
                image: '~/assets/img/slides/slide2.png',
            }
        ]
    }
},
created() {
//here some map or other way?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD2: I think it may help:

```
<template>
<div v-for='slide in parsedSlides'>
  <img :src='slide.image'>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      slides: [{
          title: 'The Ultimate Shopping Experinece',
          description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, tempore.',
          image: 'img/slides/slide1.png',
          button: 'Purchase Now'
        },
        {
          title: 'The Ultimate ',
          description: 'Szczęście piąte ipsum dolor sit amet',
          image: 'img/slides/slide2.png',
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  coptuted: {
    parsedSlides: function() {
      return this.slides.filter(slide => slide.image = require('~/assets/'+slide.image)); 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not sure that is important but this tag is inside <no-ssr> tag, because i'm using vue2-siema component (siema.js), which requires such an interpretation in nuxt.js. https://github.com/sainf/nuxt-siema-demo

Comment: this path is [compiled by nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) in template. but i would like to do this in some place in vue object.

Comment: I think the problem is in <no-ssr> tag, I think parsing the image src in  method will help, see updated answer.

Comment: This also dosn't work.
this code:
`<img :src="parseSrc('~/assets/img/slides/slide1.png')">

        <no-ssr>...</no-ssr>`
make warning "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"

Comment: Looks like webpack-related issue, maybe it will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000273/critical-dependencies-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression-webpack/37228426

Comment: I tried different paths, but it also did not help. However if i make parseSrc inside computed then webpack compile path succesfully (but this is computed so without param). Then img tag work inside and outside <no-ssr> so it's look like <no-ssr> tag is not important in this question

Comment: Could you try the function in computed from my updated answer?

Comment: this is really helpful! After a short combining, I found the answer.
First of all, there is a problem with the path compatibility in the object, so I moved the part of the nuxt ('~ / assets /) path to computed property parsedSlide, and instead of the map method I used filter (map does not work?). After this everything  run. so I do this `return this.slides.filter(slide => slide.image = require('~/assets/'+slide.image)); ` Thank you Igor!