# Image is not shown with V-FOR VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with VUE and when using a V-FOR I try to show the images but it does not show them. The file I walk with V-FOR is a simple JSON structured as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lavandería",
        "img": "../assets/img/icons/rinse.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tintorería",
        "img": "../assets/img/icons/shirt-2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Planchado",
        "img": "../assets/img/icons/iron.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Otros",
        "img": "../assets/img/icons/fashion.png"
    }
]
```

And I go through it in the following way:

```
<div class="item-servicios-select" v-for="item in services" :key="item.id">
    <div class="card select-item">
        <div class="card-content service-content">
            <div class="service-icon">
                <img class="responsive-img" :src="item.img" alt="">
                {{ item.name }}
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the mentioned error occurs that does not show the image. However if I do step the image path without using VUE works correctly:

```html
<div class="item-servicios-select">
    <div class="card select-item">
        <div class="card-content service-content">
            <div class="service-icon">
                <img class="responsive-img" src="../assets/img/icons/rinse.png" alt="">
                TEST
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attached image to show error.

[image: error with VUE]

Thank you.

Comment: Silly question, perhaps, but are the images from the API on the same host?

Comment: it's a JSON file in the same project, I'm working locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke a method and require the image as a return value:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <img class="responsive-img" :src="getImage(item)" alt="">
  {{ item.name }}
  ...
</template>
<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    getImage(item) {
      return require(item.img);
    }
  }
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: when trying, it shows me the following error:  Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/img/icons/rinse.png'"

Comment: @OscarDev Do you have a webpack loader capable of loading images set up? Such as [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)?

Comment: If someone runs into problems, I needed to hardcode the path to start from the root dir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228426/4346956

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you handle your assets, you probably need to import your images:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
    <img class="responsive-img" src="myImage" alt="">
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
import myImage from '../assets/image.png';
// ...
</script>
```

Comment: the problem would be when there are many images from some API

Comment: Ah, totally missed that. I blame the noise from the train on the morning commute. ;)